# Declare global array in codeigniter to access between different functions

Tags: php, codeigniter, global-variables

I want to declare a global variable in my model and will use it accordingly.
syntax below is just example how I want to use it, may not be proper syntax. But I want to know proper syntax for this to implement.

```
global $stddata
```

call to 1st function via ajax:

add a array of data to this global variable.

```
global $stddata = array(1=>"a",2=>"b");
```

after user triggers some event call to 2nd function via ajax:

Access the array stored in global variable above.

```
echo $stddata
```

Comment: Your global statement is incorrect, you will need to use `define('foo', 'bar');` for *assignment* and use `global $var` to import a variable into the current scope. Also being a global variable does not mean it will persist beond one request, it simply sets the scope that it can be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is similar to :

[Code Igniter - best place to declare global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17013397/code-igniter-best-place-to-declare-global-variable)

or [How to declare global variable in CodeIgniter 2.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256423/how-to-declare-global-variable-in-codeigniter-2-2)

Try this, you might get solution.

Comment: i tried using codeigniter flashdata but it is not able to take data as array..i need some other method..because many times my data will be huge..

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you put it in core controller. 
You should create MY_Controller.php file in application/core folder 
and use wanted array as you wish. 
It will be in any controller that extends MY_Constroller class.